# Electric field in a circuit when a battery is connected to it during transient phase and steady phase

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

In [this video](https://youtu.be/roIbMxiVH7U), it is mentioned that the force on charges that are inside the circuit is same throughout the wire when we close the circuit, but after the transient phase, when a steady current is achieved the forces become zero throughout the wire except resistors.

If that is true then there shouldn't be any electric field in the circuit, but how is this possible? There is a potential difference across the circuit, which means there must be an electric field and hence the force shouldn't be zero.

If I made an error in understanding or interpreting it, then please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force $F$ produced on an electric charge $Q$ in a circuit due to the presence of an electric field $E$ given by

$$F=EQ$$.

The relationship the electric field $E$ in a conductor and the voltage change $dV$ along its length $ds$ is given by the negative of the gradient of the voltage, or

$$E=-\frac{dV}{ds}$$

The wire they refer to is one that theoretically has zero resistance. For such a wire $dV$ anywhere along its length is zero. Thus the electric field is zero and a charge experiences no electrical force.

On the other hand, for a uniform resistor, the voltage across the resistor is, by Ohm's law, $V=IR$. The electric field in the resistor is then the voltage difference between the terminals of the resistor divided by its length. Then a charge moving through the resistor will experience a force due to the electric field.

It must be kept in mind however that, with the exception of superconductors, all wires have some resistance, though it is typically considered negligible compared to the resistance of circuit components. Thus there will be a voltage difference between any two points of the wire per Ohm's law, or $V=IR$. So for the wire having resistance there will be a voltage gradient and thus an electric field exerting force on the charges moving through the resistor.

Hope this helps.